# Why do we write "read" instead of "readed" and pronounce it "red"?

Tags: differences, pronunciation, orthography, past-tense, conundrum

Why do we write **read** unchanged for present and past, while *study* changes; we have *studied*.

The present form of *read* is *read*, pronounced as "*reed*".
The past form of *read* is also *read* but it is pronounced as "*red*".

Is it a regular verb or an irregular verb?

Comment: Irregular in the sense that it doesn't follow the pattern of present -> past = X -> Xed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your confusion. There are lots of verbs in English that don't follow the X -> Xed pattern. Why is *read* troubling you?

Comment: I think you might be interested in [the great vowel shift](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/why-did-only-english-undergo-the-great-vowel-shift-making-pronunciation-stray-s).

Comment: “Why” questions are nearly impossible to answer without writing a PhD thesis–length reply full of research and conflicting theories.

Comment: @tchrist: I thought the same at first look. But the OP was more likely asking about the technical reasoning, like "what are the rules behind this situation?"

Answer (score -6):

This is largely because that's what M-W.com says, observe.

[read](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/read),

```
read verb \ˈrēd\
: to look at and understand the meaning of letters, words, symbols, etc.

: to read the words of (a book, magazine, etc.)

: to speak aloud the words of (something written)
```

However, readed just shows,

[image: Readed]

Comment: I think it's the other way around. We don't say it because M-W tells us to, M-W says this because that's what we say.