# wrecking vs wracking vs wreaking

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change

What I understand so far:

Wrecking - to trash/destroy/be destroyed

Wracking - to be tortured, possibly from variant of "rack". 
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wrack also seems to mention that using the word "wrack" in the sense of torture is a mistaken usage.

Wreaking - "wreaking havoc" is the only example I can think of that uses this word, and it was apparently used in a similar manner to "wrath" archaically.
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wreak

What I want to find out:

The 3 etymologies seem to all be linked to "wrecan" via divergent evolution, but how closely linked together are the etymologies of these 3 words, and how did the final one, "wreak", end up sounding like "reek"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why did only English undergo the Great Vowel Shift, making pronunciation stray so far from spelling?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4363/why-did-only-english-undergo-the-great-vowel-shift-making-pronunciation-stray-s)

Comment: @tchrist; How is a question on separate but linked etymologies 'pronunciation-vs-spelling'? And your first comment is needlessly dismissive, bordering on offensive.

Comment: @TimLymington It says: “[stuff stuff stuff] and how did the final one, "wreak", end up sounding like "reek"?”  If that isn’t a pronunciation-vs-spelling question, I don’t know what is. It’s assuming that some way of spelling a word seems like it should be pronounced some other way, as though that’s how things worked in English. What he *should* be assuming is that *ea* is pronounced the way it is in all of *cr**ea**ture, cr**ea**tion, st**ea**k, d**ea**r, b**ea**r, h**ea**rse, h**ea**rken, h**ea**ven, b**ea**u, m**ea**nder, cetac**ea,** pa**ea**n*. Maybe it has two questions—that’s the second.

Answer (score 2):

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wreck&searchmode=none) says that *wreck* came from Scandinavian, *wrack* from Dutch, and *wreak* from Old English, although these were all descendants of the proto-Germanic verb *wrekan*.  Probably the sound changes going from proto-Germanic to Scandinavian, Dutch, and English are all reasonably predicatable, although I don't know enough about this to tell. I don't believe the change from Old English *wrecan* to Modern English *wreak* is at all unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Note that wreak and wreck do not have the same meaning. [Oxford Dictionary](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/28/wreak-havoc-wreck-havoc/) has an interesting blog about this, where they explain the difference in meaning, and says something about the entymology, that I will quote here, because it's relevant for your question:

> "The confusion of wreck and wreak is fairly common. In the Oxford English Corpus, which gathers real-world examples of usage, around 5% of all written examples of the phrase are written as ‘wreck havoc’ as opposed to ‘wreak havoc’.
>
> The overlap between the words has a long history: the Oxford English Dictionary records use of wreck as a variant spelling and pronunciation of wreak in the 16th through 18th centuries, including examples by such well-regarded authors as Milton and Oliver Goldsmith. However, this usage was regarded as obsolete by the early 20th century, and is now considered a mistake." [source](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/01/28/wreak-havoc-wreck-havoc/)