# US Equivalent to the Oxford English Dictionary

Tags: dictionaries

Apologies if this question is inappropriate for the site.

In the US, what would be equivalent to the OED? The de facto standard. I know there's the New Oxford American Dictionary but in the US does this have the same gravitas as the OED has in the UK?

Comment: 1. Merriam-Webster 2. Collins English Dictionary Sorry if I made mistake. I'm not American, but these two are famous as far as I know.

Comment: I wouldn't consider OED to be uniquely British. It covers lexical items from all parts of the English-speaking world and includes American spellings as alternates. As an American I have no hesitation consulting the OED.

Comment: I always thought the American equivalent to OED was OCD – Olde Colonies’ Dictionary. ;-)

Comment: As @JSBձոգչ points out, the American equivalent to the OED is . . . the OED.

Comment: @tchrist Are you aware of how the OED began? It was started by a man who was consigned to Broadmoor, the UK's principal asylum for the criminally insane (though nowadays it is called a *hospital*). His name was W.C.Minor. He was a madman and a murderer - and what may be of interest to the OP - he was an American. You will find his story in *The Surgeon of Crowthorne* by Simon Winchester.

Comment: @RichK, Besides oxford, doesnt' UK use cambridge dictionary too?

Comment: @Pacerier, there are plenty of others - but Oxford is probably considered the 'gold standard'

Comment: My first dictionary was a Merriam Webster Dictionary. I fell in love with it after a few days. when it defined a word it stuck to my memory better than any other dictionary has. Sadly, when I was travelling to the UK, some 20 years ago I left it with one of my niece. And my interest for word power took a different turn for the worst.

Comment: @WS2 W.C. Minor did not start the OED. He was not among its [editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Dictionary#Early_editors). He was one of the many readers for the OED (i.e. people who would read books in search of unusual usages, or unusually early instances), and contributed many examples.

Comment: @RosieF Wikipedia entry noted.

Comment: @Pacerier There are lots of dictionaries that contain the name "Oxford" or "Cambridge". But the "Oxford English Dictionary" is unique among all dictionaries of the English language, in that it provides both the etymology and historical quotations of the use of each sense of every word, some dating from centuries well before the Norman Conquest of 1066. The OED's "paper" edition runs to about 30 volumes. There is a charge for using the on-line edition, but always check whether your library has one.

Comment: And I say that as someone who would always support the Light Blues in all events including the boat race.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Probably the most famous American dictionary is the controversial *Webster’s Third New International Dictionary*, which made headlines when it was first published for taking a hard-line descriptivist stance, particularly for its treatment of the word *ain’t*. It remains the most important unabridged dictionary of American English, although it hasn’t received a major revision since it was first published in 1961.

The *Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary*, which is shorter and can be held in one hand, remains Merriam-Webster’s flagship dictionary, receiving frequent updates and revisions. It is also the best-selling dictionary of American English. The online version is accessible at [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary).

The other significant dictionary of American English is the *[American Heritage Dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Heritage_Dictionary)*, which was published by the owner of the history magazine *American Heritage*, who was appalled by the permissiveness of *Webster’s Third*. The *American Heritage Dictionary* is notable for pioneering the use of corpus linguistics in dictionary compilation, as well as for its 200-member “usage panel” who the dictionary consults when writing usage notes, reporting what percentage of the panel approved or disapproved of different contested usages.

There are othe American dictionaries which are well-regarded but not as well-known, such as the *Oxford American*, *Random House*, and *Webster’s New World*. Americans generally don’t distinguish among dictionaries and typically refer to all dictionaries as “the dictionary”, as in “I’ll look that up in the dictionary”.

Comment: +1 for giving the nod to my go-to dictionary, *Webster's Third New International*. I can actually hold it in one hand, but with extreme difficulty. In fact, I had a woodworking friend of mine craft me a stand for it, which functions also as a shrine.

Comment: esperluette has pointed out the difference beteween the OED and the dictionaries listed above. None of them compare in function, showing the history of a word. While the OED is missing some Americanisms, it is still the only standard I know for what it does.

Comment: @nohat, Is webster even "controversial" now?

Answer (score 10):

The OED is a historical dictionary, which means it shows the meanings of words as they developed over time. People *use* it as a standard, but it does not set out to be one, and the [editors of the OED discourage people](http://www.oed.com/public/collecting/collecting-the-evidence) from deciding whether or not to use a word based solely on its inclusion in the OED.

The New Oxford American Dictionary is not a historical dictionary, but a dictionary of current English, and is much smaller than the OED in the number of terms covered. (If you have a Mac, you already have this dictionary, because it's the dictionary used by the Dictionary Widget in the dashboard.)

If you are looking for a dictionary that set itself up as a standard, especially for scientific and technical vocabulary of the day you might look at the [Century Dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=A3gAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA315&dq=%22the+century+dictionary%22&hl=en&ei=cCtZTfXTB5SftweXmrTuDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20century%20dictionary%22&f=false)(commentary at link). It has not been updated for about a hundred years, though.

The bigger question is: what do you want a standard for?

- To tell you whether or not something is a word? No dictionary will tell you that, only usage.
- Etymology? The OED is among the best for etymology, although there are other sites that have better ones for particular words (and despite the Century's age, its etymologies are on a par with the OED).
- Advice on correct or accepted usage? You'd be better off with the Dictionary of Modern American Usage.
- An impressive book to put on a stand? True dictionary aficionados like Merriam Webster's Second International (rather than the third), as a prestige thing. (Or again, a copy of the Century, although that's ten volumes.)

Comment: Hmm, in the link , where is the exact quote that says "editors of the OED discourage people from deciding whether or not to use a word based solely on its inclusion in the OED"?

Answer (score 6):

New Oxford American Dictionary (NOAD) is part of the great work done by the OED group and does pull the same weight as the rest of their publications.  The major difference is that the NOAD presents the American variant spellings first and contains words and usage that are not used in other English dialects.

Comment: I disagree! My case against NOAD: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499613/which-definition-of-mitzvah-and-23-others-is-correct

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a standard, but the best sellers should have the greatest influence. Judging by the current best-sellers on Amazon, they are:

1. Merriam-Webster
2. American Heritage
3. Webster's New World
4. New Oxford American

Comment: That doesn't follow at all - what's popular is completely different from what's accepted as *the standard* or *authoritative*. What's popular largely depends on price, whereas authoritative works are often lengthy and expensive.

Comment: @TrevorD, Not just price, but size. And many other things.