# What dictionary should be used when citing the dictionary in an American PhD-level dissertation?

Tags: dictionaries

In an Australian PhD dissertation, the Oxford English Dictionary would be the obvious choice when needing to make reference to a dictionary definition.

However, I am writing for an audience of (mostly) American computer scientists and would like to follow US conventions.

**Which dictionary would be widely regarded as the source of the most authoritative, prestigious and "academic" definitions within the US?**

(There is a related question at [US Equivalent to the Oxford English Dictionary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12480/us-equivalent-to-the-oxford-english-dictionary) but the question and answers are based on a reader's point of view, rather than as an authoritative source)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Comment: @DavidM We often migrate these sorts of questions to [meta]; it's one of the other “off-topic” close reasons.

Comment: The OED is good for any Anglophone PhD, except in cases of specialized terminology or dialectal variants.

Comment: I suggest you check with the host, university or institution where you will be presenting. They may have a preferred set of references; I suspect they will be shocked if you follow it.

Comment: The American equivalent to the OED is the OED. There is nothing else like it.

Comment: @DavidM, I see your point. However, I would argue that I have identified many possible dictionaries myself. I am seeking guidance on which one would be best received by my US readers. I am writing about meanings in the English language (as part of a technical PhD) and wish for the definitions to be taken seriously.

Comment: John Lawler and @tchrist --> I believe you've answered my question. Thanks. If nobody enters an answer, in a few hours I'll copy your comments into the answer field and then accept that as the answer.

Comment: @Ben: this would be an ideal post on the [Academia Stack Exchange site](http://academia.stackexchange.com).