# Does any English dialect use any non-English foreign letters in their alphabet?

Tags: orthography, latin, alphabet, is-it-a-rule, portuguese

## Which English dialects use non-English foreign letters in their alphabets?

Does any English dialect currently include any foreign letters as part of their alphabet? Are any English dialects currently planning to add foreign letters to their alphabet in the future?

For example, under the international treaty known in English as the [*Portuguese Language Orthographic Agreement of 1990*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990), the official Portuguese alphabet was **officially extended** by three foreign letters:<sup>1</sup>

- K: *capa*, pronounced like "kappa"
- Y: pronounced *ípsilon* or *ipsilão* or *i greg*
- W: pronounced *dáblio* [think *diabolically*] (Hmmm, Portuguese speakers certainly do hate W.)

There are many English dialects. For example, I know about the existence of British English and American English, and I guess there are a couple of hundred more English dialects beyond those two alone.

Do any of these English dialects include any foreign letters?

---

1. From [Wikipedia’s article on the 1990 spelling agreement](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acordo_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1990#Bases):

   > Base I – Do alfabeto e dos nomes próprios estrangeiros e seus derivados: Descreve o alfabeto com a designação usualmente dada a cada letra, introduzindo a letra *w* e restaurando *k* e *y*, proscritas do alfabeto português desde 1911 em Portugal e desde 1943 no Brasil. Mantêm-se, no entanto, as regras fixadas anteriormente que restringem o seu uso às abreviaturas, palavras de origem estrangeira ou seus derivados, assim como unidades de medida de curso internacional (p.ex., *kilowatt*, citado explicitamente no Acordo).
   >
   > #### [(translation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Language_Orthographic_Agreement_of_1990#Changes)
   >
   > It will also add three letters (K, W, and Y) to the Portuguese alphabet, making it equal to the ISO basic Latin alphabet.

Comment: SEE ALSO: [Haf**þ**ór Júlíus Björnsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haf%C3%BE%C3%B3r_J%C3%BAl%C3%ADus_Bj%C3%B6rnsson), [**Æ**var Arnfjör**ð** Bjarmason](http://xn--var-xla.net/), and [La**ȝ**amon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layamon) — just to name a few, plus [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58489/2085).

Comment: Dialects are spoken; alphabets are written. All English dialects use the same alphabet. There are a lot of jots and tittles one can add with borrowed words in foreign spellings, but they're not part of English orthography.

Comment: @tchrist   ['dɑ.bliʊ] not [diáblio]

Comment: @Centaurus Thanks, I was just dressing up what the asker had already written there, and that curious spelling with the extra *-i-* was what I had found. Fixed now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual pattern is that words that are still perceived as foreign retain their original spelling, but if they become a part of the English lexicon, the spelling is modified to a more English-seeming orthography. For instance, Conan Doyle used the spelling *cañon* at around the beginning of the twentieth century for a word we now spell as *canyon*. Where the characters are truly uncommon, English has always tended to transliterate into existing symbols.

We have and use diacriticals in English, although they seem to have fallen out of use since the introduction of word processing. One still often sees a diaeresis used in *naïve* or *noël*, but one rarely sees *coöperate* anymore. We also  use ligature graphemes like *ash* (Æ or æ), but the trend has been toward either dropping one of the two ligated letters or setting the letters separately.

Comment: Did one once see coöperate anywhere other than the NYT? I'm used to seeing it hyphenated as co-operate.

Comment: It was certainly standard usage in Canada and the UK in the '60s and earlier.

Comment: Speaking of rarely seen forms, *rôle* is gone too.

Comment: The rôle of *rôle* is now being played by *role*. I never like it when they change the actors mid-series.

Comment: I always use rôle - just to be pretentious!

Answer (score 2):

> Does any of them include or plan to include foreign letters?

It is possible that English alphabet will include letters that are not included in the today alphabet, in the same way English passed from the alphabet used in Old English to the nowadays alphabet.
I cannot say it is planned, as English doesn't have an academy (or any authoritative agency, see [Regulatory bodies and authoritative dictionaries for English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/regulatory-bodies-and-authoritative-dictionaries-for-english)) that plans such things, or proposes those things.

Comment: The link to the other question was a kind suggestion™ from RegDwight.

Comment: Alphabet is not governed by any central bordies. As an example, I can cite Russia where the state civic language is modern Russian and Russian Orthodox Church uses [Slavonic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Slavonic_language) which does not have even common typographic letters with Russian (or even words). [An example in Church Slavonic](http://www.orthlib.info/Gospels/01-Matthew_1mf.pdf). Besides, [cyrillic alphabet is used in over 100 countries+languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_using_Cyrillic)

Comment: @vgv8: you should know better than post that. The Russian alphabet has a long history of changes by "central bodies", starting with Peter the Great and ending with the October Revolution, when the Bolsheviks kicked out four letters. Oh, and [Church Slavonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Slavonic_language) is a different language altogether, so *no wonder* that it uses a different alphabet, just like many other Slavic languages do — Ukrainian, Bulgarian, Serbian, Czech, Polish, to name but a few.

Comment: @RegDwight, I hope you know the origin of cyrillics and its name. It is derived from Greek alphabet and was created by Greeks  [Cyril and Metodius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saints_Cyril_and_Methodius) in Greece. I cannot recall how and when Russians governed Greece, Serbia, Montenegro, etc. I hope they did not distort Greek alphabet altogether?

Comment: @GennadyVaninГеннадийВанин As is actually mentioned in the Wikipedia article you linked to, Cyril and Metodius did **not** create the Cyrillic alphabet. Students of their school did, but they themselves did not.

Answer (score 2):

There are some loanwords from French, some of them preserving original spelling. For example "façade" (although in English spelling "facade" is also accepted).

Another thing that comes into mind is load from German, prefix "über-", although it's not really part of official language.

In science -- 1Å (ångström) == 0.1nm. Not sure if you'd count that as part of language...

Not sure where you'd put Æ, after all it's not foreign, it's Old English.

Comment: Thanks. This reminded me that who;e I studied English in primary schhol the transcription of sounds for reading English words was given with the use of Æ and other "non-English" letters.

Comment: @vgv8: The transcription of English sounds uses letters that are not part of the English alphabet; for example, _ə_ (schwa) is used for the _uh_ sound, but that letter is not part of the English alphabet.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, what are the origins of those symbols? I always thought before that they were invented by pedagogues to torture school children

Comment: @vgv8: they’re probably [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) symbols, in this case; more generally, see [pronunciation respelling systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English).

Comment: Diacritics do **not** count as separate letters in the English alphabet. So with imported loanwords *na**ï**ve, fa**ç**ade, jalape**ñ**os*, those are still the same English letters, just with extra diacritics added. This is not always true in the source language; for example, in Spanish the *ñ* is considered a letter in its own right not an *n* with a diacritic.  In contrast, glyphs like [*þ, ð, ȝ, ƿ* (respectively named *thorn, eth, yogh, wynn*) from Old English and Middle English](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58489) which we now seldom use truly **are** different letters altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are no letters in the [Latin alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_basic_Latin_alphabet) which are missing from English, so there is nothing more to add. On the contrary, English used to have more letters in the past, [such as eth and thorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_Latin_alphabet). They are not likely to come back, I presume.

As for letters with diacritics, there are several words, primarily (or always?) borrowed from French, that are often written in English with diacritics, such as naïve, naïveté, fiancé.

Comment: +1 thanks. One can directly type K(, Y, W) in Portuguese keyboard. How one does type the letters with diacritics in US keyboard?

Comment: I'm not sure how most people do it, but I usually use the `Alt` key with the numeric pad. Try `Alt+0233` (é) or `Alt+0239` (ï). By the way, you can find `eth` and `thorn` there as well (`0240, 0254`), because they are still used in Icelandic. I believe there are easier ways to do it in specific word-processors, such as Word.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the classical Latin alphabet had 23 letters as J was usually written with I, and U with V;  W was a development from the double letters VV (or UU).

Comment: Actually, the alphabet used in English is only part of the Latin alphabet, which includes also letters like _à_, _è_, _ì_, the _Latin capital letter R with double grave_, or the _Latin capital letter A with ogonek_.

Comment: @ kiamlaluno: Those characters are in "Latin script" according to Unicode and the like, but they are most certainly not part of the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Can you give a source? Why did you mention these and not others, such as é and ü?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: The alphabet used from Spanish and Italian, for example, is still the Latin alphabet. English doesn't use accented letters, but those are still part of the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @Ilya Kogan: I listed just few of the Latin alphabet letters; it doesn't make sense to list all of them, as few of them are enough to express what I mean.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Ok, this is disputable. Anyway, I guess I should have just said "letters in the Latin alphabet without diacritics".

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, Spanish and Italian are not the Latin alphabet. (Even the letters J, U, W may be questionable, but they are included in the "ISO Basic Latin alphabet" linked above). If you look at Wikipedia, [Italian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_alphabet) says "Italian alphabet is a variant of the Latin alphabet" and [Spanish alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_alphabet#Alphabet) says "Spanish alphabet […] is the Latin alphabet with one additional letter: eñe (‹ñ›), making exactly 27". The other characters are in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-derived_alphabet

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: [Italian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language) is said to be written using the Latin alphabet. Following what you say, then also the alphabet used in English is an extension of the Latin alphabet, as Latin only used uppercase letters.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Latin did not use only uppercase letters. The lowercase letters we use now are quite different in style to the ones used in the Republic two millennia ago, and the way we use and distribute upper- and lowercase letters is quite different, too; but even back then they had ‘upper- and lowercase’ letters.

Comment: Thorn and eth were the two remaining NATIVE runic characters.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _Classical Latin did not contain sentence punctuation, [letter case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin#CITEREFDiringer1996), or interword spacing, but apices were sometimes used to distinguish length in vowels and the interpunct was used at times to separate words._

Comment: I know it because in Italy you find many classical Latin inscriptions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno If you define letter case strictly as how we currently use it in Latin-based scripts, then no, Latin did not have letter case. Nor did any of the other languages that used Latin-based scripts until some time in the Middle Ages. That is not the only way you can define ‘upper-’ and ‘lowercase’, however. Our way of using upper- and lowercase letters is fairly recent; lowercase letters are historically cursive variants used for less formal writing, and Classical Latin most certainly did have [that type of lowercase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_cursive).

Answer (score 0):

The English word "Hawaiʻi" has a okina in it between the last two is. The okina looks like a left quotation sign, sort of, but it is actually one of the 13 letters of the Hawaiian language. From Wikipedia: The ʻokina, also called by several other names, is a unicameral consonant letter used within the Latin script to mark the phonetic glottal stop, as it is used in many Polynesian languages. From Wordnik: n. The Hawaiian apostrophe-like letter (ʻ) used to indicate the glottal stop consonant.
Etymologies
Sorry, no etymologies found.

Comment: Interesting  but it doesn't answer the question. We have not added the okina to the English alphabet. And *Hawaii* is usually spelled without it.

Comment: @ John Lawler I'm with John Lawler: "dialects are spoken; alphabets are written."  The question asked for NON-ENGLISH FOREIGN LETTERS. As I see it dialects don't have alphabets, but I believe my answer is in the spirit of the question. As for the spelling of our 50th state, the official spelling uses the okina:Hawaii or Hawai'i: What's the official spelling?

Updated: Mar 31, 2016 7:12 PM EDT You've seen the version with the okina or glottal stop between the two i's and others without. The state's “Hawaii Board on Geographic Names” is proposing a spelling change (Continued)

Comment: @AlanCarmack “Technically it’s not a name change. It’s a spelling correction,” said Kamana’o Mills, Hawaii Board on Geographic Names. “By leaving out the okina, it’s considered a misspelling. It’s like if we spelled ‘apple’ pple and excluded the a.” I admit I'm not certain the corrected spelling has been adopted, but I stand by my answer.

Comment: The apostrophe is already part of English spelling. Also, an apostrophe is not part of an alphabet.

Comment: @Mitch I agree with your comment, but it's impertinent. When Wordnik says that the okina is the "Hawaiian apostrophe-like letter (ʻ) used to indicate the glottal stop consonant," it means that the letter, okina, from the Hawaiian alphabet is shaped like an apostrophe. But it is a letter, not just a diacritic or a punctuation mark; it comes from an alphabet other than the English alphabet and is used in a well-known English word.