# What is this letter/symbol called?

Tags: dictionaries, archaicisms, old-english, symbols

I found it in an old dictionary and I'm not sure what it means. It looks like the number "3", but the top of the three has been flattened(and slightly curved).

I've only seen this in three or four words.

[[Link to a dictionary on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008PDTE3I)]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogh ?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58470/ye-olde-english-alphabet-question-any-other-letters-lost-besides-thorn-edh-an

Comment: "Yogh, to me, resembles  a three / a little bit flattened  above  / and sounds a note so deep in the throat / as only the  Dutch could love ...." --  from Cat Faber, _Yogh and Aesh and Thorn_, which borrows Kipling's _Oak and Ash and Thorn_ to discuss lingustic history.

Comment: Ezh was the symbol I was looking for, however thanks for also bringing to my attention "Yogh"! Also @tchrist, thanks for the link to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't follow that link to anything useful, but pending the addition of a picture to the question I'll provisionally suggest that what you describe sounds like it is could just about be the letter yogh (capital Ȝ, lowercase ȝ), but more likely the letter ezh (capital Ʒ, lowercase ʒ).

ʒ was invented for a system of English phonetics, and survives in the IPA.

There was also an old scribal abbreviation for the unit *dram*/*drachm* that was so close to ʒ in appearance that the symbols are essentially merged at least as far as modern computing use goes (though some use ȝ rather than ʒ there).

Comment: There's also [yogh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogh), **ȝ**.

Comment: @JohnLawler as mentioned.