# Is there any grammar or vocabulary reference reliable enough?

Tags: resources

> **Duplicate of:**
>   [Regulatory bodies and authoritative dictionaries for English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/regulatory-bodies-and-authoritative-dictionaries-for-english)

In other languages there are official institutions which control the development of the language and provide official references so the users of the language can go there to check how to use the language when they have a doubt. For example in Spanish that reference is online and can be freely checked by any user.

I wonder if there is any similar official organization which provides references or dictionaries for users. How do native speakers know what is correct or not when they have a doubt? Where can they check it? Is there any free online resource with enough reliability for that?